# jQuery: fadeIn() and fadeOut() before unload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and been trying to figure this out.

I have a course assignment where I have to make an event handler for a page unload in JQuery that when fired will fadeout(3000) a div and then the text 'Thank you' will fadein(3000).  I'm assuming what the instructor means is to have a button or link that leaves the window and goes to another page but first executes the fadeIn/FadeOut.

**I'm not having any issues w/ the FadeIn/FadeOut option.  I'm having the issue w/ the unload ... how do I get it to go to a new page but first execute a fadeOut(2000)/fadeIn(2000)?**

I'm having a problem figuring this out.  As far as I understand unload is compatable only w/ $(window), so the only that I can really do is have an alert?

This is what I have so far, but this is not an unload, I'm trying to figure out how to have this effect work once you are unloading. Is that even possible?

**JQ**

```
$(function () {
    $(".btn1").click(function () {
        $("#fadeout").fadeOut(3000);
        $("#thankyou").fadeIn(3000);
    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
btn1 {
display:none;}
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn1" class="btn1">CLICK</button>
```

Would I add a delay to close the window and link something else at the same time when you hit the button?

Comment: What do you mean with unload? Did you mean onLoad?

Comment: i mean .unload().  the even handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".btn1").click(function() {
  $("#fadeout").fadeOut(3000, function() {
    $("#thankyou").fadeIn(3000, function() {
      location="url";
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#thankyou {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='fadeout'>Hello World!</div>
<div id='thankyou'>Thank you!</div>
<button class='btn1'>Click</button>
```

This?

Comment: this is great! thank you.  but there is no way to do it with the unload() event handler is there?

Comment: I believe that onbeforeunload or unload event handlers can delay the unloading of the page BUT it cannot animate the page at the same time. It sort of freezes the page so you cannot see the animation :

Comment: yeah that's what I figured, which is why I was having such a difficult time wrapping my head around this assignment.